# How can i use 'Ellipsis style' in Multiline Situation?

Tags: html, html-table, ellipsis, pre

i'm stuck in the tiny problem. Please help me.

[--> Please Visit my fiddle (Click here).](http://jsfiddle.net/vydsm/)

1. How can i apply 'ellipsis' style in this situation ?
2. How can i overcome obstacle such as `<pre>` and `<td>` for apply `<ellipsis>` style?
3. Don't remove `<pre>` and `<td>`  for solve this problem.

Thanks, for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a list for your hehe-text and the following style:

```
li { width: 100%; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

You can use another block Element, too, if you prefer.